# call function in controller from template.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am new to AngularJS, Somehow while going through many sites now I am able to create a directive for showing some data.Now I need to send some data to controller by clicking the button. I need to know the proper way of doing this

I have created the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/YogCFtd7NwA4urhao464?p=preview)

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="movieDesc">
    <div ng-repeat="m in movies" movies="m"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Directive and Controller**

```
// Code goes here

angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('movieDesc', function($scope) {

  $scope.movies = [{
    name: 'abc',
    desc: 'this is desc text for the movie',
    pic: 'http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/134/abstract-geometric-background-triangle-and-square-black_134053397.jpg'
  }, {
    name: 'def',
    desc: 'this is desc text for the movie def',
    pic: 'http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/201/abstract-modern-banner-background-of-geometric-shapes-abstract-geometric-form_201768245.jpg'
  }, {
    name: 'ghi',
    desc: 'this is desc text for the movie ghi',
    pic: 'http://www.cianellistudios.com/images/abstract-art/abstract-art-infinite-150.jpg'
  }]

  $scope.saveData = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }

});

angular.module('app').directive('movies', function() {
return {
  templateUrl: "movieCard.html",
  restrict: "EA",
  scope: {
    movies: '='
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.addClass('moviesBox');
    var clickedFn = function() {
      alert("clicked");
    };
    console.log("console", element[0].querySelector('.btnSelect'));
    var $this = element[0].querySelector('.btnSelect');
    $($this).click(function() {
      alert(scope.movies.desc)
    })

  }

}

})
```

**My Template**

```
<div>
  <div>
    <b>Name:</b> {{movies.name}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>Description:</b> {{movies.desc}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="{{movies.pic}}" />
  </div>
    <div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="movies.someText">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="btnSelect" type="button" value="Desc" ng-click="clickedFn()">
  </div>
   <div>
    <input class="btnSelect" type="button" value="Save Data" ng-click="saveData({{movies}})">
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to send the data to the controller's `$scope.saveData()` function, the data will be entered through the textbox. I have given it as `ng-model="movies.someText"` which I suppose is the wrong way.

So please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `&` [scope binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

```
scope: {
    movies: '=',
    save: '&'
},
```

and in the directive template

```
<input type="button" ng-click="save({movie: movies})" ...>
```

You then bind the controller method via

```
<div ng-repeat="m in movies" movies="m" save="saveData(movie)"></div>
```

Note the argument name passed to the controller function matches the object key in the directive template.

https://plnkr.co/edit/9bF5FDea6wLn7vcGvEzU?p=preview

---

While you're there, use `ng-src` instead of `src` to avoid a 404 request for a non-existent image

```
<img ng-src="{{movies.pic}}" />
```

Comment: never knew about ng-src and src, thanks for the explanation, now I will remember this for lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass saveData as a parameter like this:

```
<body ng-controller="movieDesc">
<div ng-repeat="m in movies" movies="m" save-data="saveData()"></div>
```

And you get back in your directive like this:

```
    return {
       templateUrl: "movieCard.html",
       restrict: "EA",
       scope: {
         movies: '=',
         saveData:'='
       },
       link: ...
```

And then in your template.html, you don't need to use '`{{}}`' :

```
<input class="btnSelect" type="button" value="Save Data" ng-click="saveData(movies)">
```

Comment: how should I call it on the button click??

Comment: like this: <input class="btnSelect" type="button" value="Save Data" ng-click="saveData(movies)">

Comment: Your example worked before you edited it to use the `&` binding instead of your original `=` binding. Now it doesn't. You also have a typo at `save-sata`

Comment: upvoted, but still ur example didnt worked, but thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
 <body ng-controller="movieDesc">
    <div ng-repeat="m in movies" movies="m">
      <movies-dir 
         movies="m" save-data="saveData(movie)"></movies-dir>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Directive and Controller**

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
 .controller('movieDesc', function($scope) {

     $scope.movies = [/* movie object array data */]

     $scope.saveData = function(movie) {
         console.log(movie);
     }

  });

 angular.module('app').directive('moviesDir', function() {
    return {
       templateUrl: "movieCard.html",
       restrict: "EA",
       scope: {
          movies: '=',
         saveData: '&'
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

       }

    }

 })
```

**Template**

```
  <div>
     <input class="btnSelect" type="button" value="Save Data" ng-click="saveData({ 'movie': movies  })">
 </div>
```